# How to get a JSON file if the URL is a redirect?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I have an app (similar to the Employee Directory example) that pulls down a JSON file from the client's server on a daily basis (Business Continuity info that rarely changes).

Currently I have the URL as a variable in my globals.js which points to their internal web server.

They now want to make the URL variable point to a URL which is in fact a URL redirect. The redirect will be dynamic (well, sort of) that will point to where the file resides.

The "autoRedirect" property does not seem to be working for this on either the iOS or Android builds.

Does anyone have any ideas as to how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that the redirects switches protocol? Like from `http` to `https` or visa versa? Because that might indeed not work as its considered bad practice.

If not, then it it looks like you've found a bug. Please check if this is a known issue at the [Appcelerator JIRA](https://jira.appcelerator.org). If it's not, create a ticket, link to this question but also provide reproducible code, steps and environment information in the ticket itself. Don't forget to drop a link to the ticket here so that others can watch it with you.